# Can I treat the thermal shock test temperature as the continuous operating temperature of a conformal coating?

Tags: pcb-design, temperature, thermal, pcb-assembly, conformal-coating

We are using this conformal coating on our design, [HumiSeal 1B73EPA](https://chasecorp.com/humiseal1/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2018/10/1B73-EPA-TDS-1-1.pdf).
However, it does not state in the datasheet the continuous operating temperature for the coating, only the thermal shock test temperature:
[image]

From my understanding, the operating temperature of a product is determined in a similar fashion. Is it safe to treat the stated thermal shock temperature as its continuous operating temperature?

Comment: Check what that MIL spec test involves. If it's a long period cycling then you can. But what about the glass transition temperature?

Comment: http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-I/MIL-I-46058C_11366/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the (inactive) [MIL spec](https://www.simtalltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/MIL-I-46058C.pdf):

> 6.1.6 Operating temperature. These coatings are normally useful at temperatures up to 125°C (200°C for type SR), but the useful life of
> the deposited coating can be extended by reducing the operating
> temperature. The effect of a humid environment is to reduce the useful
> life.

SR is silicone, and yours is acrylic.

Thermal shock (specified in [another standard](https://nepp.nasa.gov/DocUploads/1F6AB74B-4517-4AD0-A34813268E75B8EB/MIL-STD-202.pdf)) is a 50 cycle test with with exposure at temperature extremes long enough to guarantee it has stabilized (see the table, it depends on mass of the item, as low as 15 minutes), so not very representative of possible deterioration at high temperature:

[image]